# Pivot on ROWS instead of COLUMNS

Tags: excel, pivot

I've been tasked to fix a pivot table in a spreadsheet that was migrated from Google Sheets to SharePoint.
All the tabs and formulas are working but a pivot was totally lost.
I've found that Excel in SharePoint works significantly different than Excel2016, and when exported from SharePoint some of the formulas 'break'.

My main question is can SharePoint Excel create a new source (Excel SQL, vba, whatever) to use for a pivot?
The source for the pivot is in an unusual format:
[image: Source Data]

I'd like to use Date / Issue / Activity / Exceptions as columns for the pivot with the dates (across the top) to be used as rows.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpivot your data.

Got to insert>table to make your data a table.

Then go to data> from table.

Now select the columns that aren't dates using shift, then right click>unpivot other columns.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it is appreciated. The data of the source is not pivoted, I'd like to use it to create a new pivot as specified